# Mouseover d3.js map with different layers

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, topojson

I made my TopoJSON with 3 different administrative levels. During mouseover, I would like the object from Level 2 to be highlighted. However, due to layering, the object could only detect the mouse event if there is no object above it (from, let's say, Level 3). It's a javascript issue, I could simply change the z-index of each levels (either by CSS or in the script). I also tried reordering the calls for each level. However, I read somewhere that d3.js has it's own way of processing the objects, so the approaches I mentioned didn't seem to work.

How do I make sure that the object that I want stays on top?

Comment: SVG doesn't have a z-index -- objects are rendered in the order in which they are added to the DOM tree. Add the objects you want to appear on top last.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I tried a few combinations and weirdly enough, the first object that I add appears on top.

Comment: If you have asynchronous callbacks, the order in which the elements are added may not be what you think it is. The same goes if you're using `g` elements to group other elements.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, what worked for me is FIRST adding the object with the event listener. AND make sure that the object's fill color exists (not set to none).